# lock in detection based denoising using matlab?

Tags: matlab, noise, detection

What are the limitations of implementing the lock in detection technique in matlab?
I have time varying data with known frequency with huge background noise. The reference signal is also available. How efficiently can i recover the signal from the noise using the software implementation of the lock in detection?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

You say the reference signal is available. Have you tried multiplying your noisy signal by the reference signal? Do you also have a 90-degree shifted reference signal?

Comment: I tried multiplying the signal with the reference and taking mean, but the result is not good. I only need the amplitude of the signal, so the 90-degree reference needed then?

Comment: Why dont you edit your question and add all the information of what you have tried and where did you fail?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to read the questions, comments and answers here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/34176/41790